# React Native library for displaying 360 panorams

Tags: react-native, 360-panorama

Looking for library or way to display 360 images in React Native Android app. In google all libs are deprecated and I keep facing the same unsolved problems that are mentioned in issues (for ex in the react-native-360 lib)

Tried to use about 10 libraries but all of them are at least 2 yrs old and don't work.